# I want to know can I use JQuery $.post to upload a file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)
>   [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

I use $.post to send my form data to a php page for adding to database.
I wanted to know can I use the same way to upload files? or I have to use JQuery plugins for doing that? here is my code:

```
$.post("demo.php",{name:$("#name").value,family:$("#family").value},function(result){
   $("#message").html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about uploading a file via the post command using jQuery, but frankly it's just easier to use a plugin that can also handle cool HTML 5 support like drag and drop. One that I found worked really well is https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

And it's under the MIT license, so you should be good in that perspective.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't manage asynchronous file upload using `$.post`

Use a plugin instead, I have used [Blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and it gave me good results.